# Creating Double Linked List Issue

Tags: c

Our assignment is to first create a Double linked list and then sort it. I am currently stuck on the first part. For some reason the second node is not added until  third node is not created and that continues on all up until i enter the last node which is not included but a node with a 0 value is added instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "node.h"
#include "node.c"


int main(){
    printf("Enter the values, once finished enter 0 to stop.\n");
    int v;
    scanf("%d",&v);
    struct mynode headnode = {v};
    struct mynode *hpoint = &headnode;
    struct mynode **hpointp = &hpoint;
    while (v!=0){
        struct mynode *nn1 = (struct mynode*)malloc(sizeof(struct mynode));
        struct mynode *endnode = *hpointp;
        scanf("%d",&nn1->value); // using this because value is a constant in mynode and it wont let me write to it directly
        nn1->next = NULL;
        v = nn1->value;
        if (v == 0){
            free(nn1);
            break;
        }

            while(endnode->next != NULL){
                endnode = endnode->next;
            } 

        endnode->next = nn1;
        nn1->prev = endnode;
        printlist(hpoint);
    }
    printlist(hpoint);

    return 0;

}




here is the printlist function as well just in case i made a mistake there.


void printlist(struct mynode* n){
    if (n->next == NULL && n->prev == NULL ){
        printf("%d",n->value);
    }

    while (n->next != NULL){
        printf("%d <===> ",n->value);
        n = n->next;
        if (n->next == NULL){
            printf("%d\n",n->next);
        } 
    }
}
```

lastly here is the node header file

```
#ifndef node_h
#define node_h

struct mynode{
    int const value;
    struct mynode *next;
    struct mynode *prev;
};

//struct mynode *insertsort(struct mynode*);

void printlist(struct mynode*);

#endif
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. By "assignment" I assume you got this for some C programming class. They should tell you not to include C files but only header files. That's bad style.

Comment: I `printlist` you do not check if you get a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your print function looks complicated. You can simply loop until `n` is `NULL` and print the values.

```
void printlist(struct mynode* n){
    while(n) {
        printf("%d <===>",n->value);
        n=n->next;
    }
    printf("0");
}
```